# How might I make a template file in Jade so I can include it in other pages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I've made a header file that I would like to include in all my pages, it also includes the navbar and has the body in it to in a nutshell it is like this

```
!!!
html
 head
  title
 body
```

I would like to be able to include it in any other file, and be able to continue to write inside the body, if I try to include it now, anything I write in the new file appears after the closing `</html>` so how might I be able to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `block`, but think the other way. Create a base.jade, which contains the shared part, and extend this.

```
!!!
html
  head
    title
  body 
    block main
      p Hello
```

than in your other files:

```
extends base
block append body
  p World
```

this will result in

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>World</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Than there's a command `include`, which is not what you want, but maybe worth mention.

```
!!!
html
  head
    include head.jade
  body 
    block main
```

More info in the [docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme)